# Manage flags in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

All,
i am searching in a list of fields those who has the type clob and i am writing it separed by a comma like this [field1, field2, ... fieldn]

my problem is how to identify the first matched field to write it without comma ( i can't use position() because the first field matched can be the first of the list or the last of the list)

I want to make this algorithm in xslt,

```
variable is_first = TRUE;

if(is_first) {
     do smthng;
     isfirst = False;
}
```

Comment: You're asking "how do I implement this algorithm".  A better question would be "this is the problem I'm trying to solve, what algorithm should I use".

Comment: I tried improve my answer according to your questions edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not possible to make something like this in xslt since variable are immutable. There probably could be workarounds but you have to specify your need in more details.

edit:

If your input is string with values separated by commas...

```
<xsl:variable name="inputString" select="'field1,field2,field3a,field4,field3b'" />
```

... you could use `tokenize()` functions...

```
<xsl:variable name="tokenized" select="tokenize($inputString, ',')" />
```

... and then select items corresponding to your condition

```
<!-- Select item corresponding to condition (e.g. it contains 3). Take first one if there are several such items -->
<xsl:value-of select="$tokenized[contains(., '3')][1]" />
```

Edit2:

You can use `separator` attribute of `xsl:value-of` (xslt 2.0) for output of delimited values.

Assuming following variable

```
<xsl:variable name="list">
    <item>first</item>
    <item>second</item>
    <item>third</item>
</xsl:variable>
```

this `<xsl:value-of select="$list/item" separator="," />` makes desired output `first,second,third`

Comment: in fact to explain more: i want an output "field1,field2 ...fieldn" not an input, my problem is how to write the comma between fields in my xsl

Comment: I've been away for some time so sorry for later response. I improved my answer - check it please.

Answer (score -1):

You need to write this using functional code rather than procedural code. It's not possible to do the conversion without seeing the context (it's much easier to work from the problem rather than from the solution in a lower-level language).

But the most common equivalent in XSLT would take the form

```
<xsl:for-each select=".....">
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1"><!-- first time code --></xsl:if>
  ....
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: this is true if only the first matched element is the first one in the list (position()=1) in my case the first matched one is (position()=6) that's why i'amsearching to activate a first flag

Comment: Well, if you're going to downvote my answer because I failed to guess information that wasn't in the question, then I'm going to downvote the question, so there.